# what is the best way to design newsletter by tables?

Tags: html, css, newsletter

what is the best way to design newsletter by tables ?

which programs can help me about that ??

Comment: welcome to SO: If you are referring to database schema,  have a look at databaseanswers.com to see if they have a pre-rolled schema you could use.

Comment: By "tables", what do you mean? The HTML `<table>` tag? Or tables from a database? Can you provide any more details on what you're trying to accomplish? Are you looking for a pre-defined template? An editor?

Comment: i will use <table> tag so is the best and working with most email engines.. but is hard work how i can design easily ?

Comment: [zen-coding](http://code.google.com/p/zen-coding/) + [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) = Win

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many people like [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) as an HTML editor.

If you want WYSIWYG, try [Adobe Dreamweaver](http://www.adobe.com/products/dreamweaver/).

It's not really clear what you're asking here, and you don't provide enough specifics about your platform/environment to give any better answers.

Answer (score 0):

As newsletters tend to work best with inline styled content, which doesn't lend itself too well to editing, consider styling regularly first and then running your markup through an inline converter, such as [this one](http://premailer.dialect.ca/).